# HTML contenteditable with expanded and centered text

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I want an editable field (like a `textarea` but not necessarily) whose text is centered and whose borders expand when the text reaches them. The closest I've come to a (simple) solution is this:

```html
<p style="text-align: center; width: 100px; border: 2px solid;" contenteditable="true" nowrap>Hello</p>
```

Unfortunately, the `nowrap` property on `<p>` works only on Firefox and the text remains centered on 50px instead of the center of the longest line of the paragraph. What else can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set inline block + min width, so that the box will expaned to match the text length, also use CSS `white-space:nowrap;` instead of the HTML `nowrap` attribute.

```css
p {
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the crossbrowser problem, but not the other problem.

Comment: Look at my snippet. Write something in the text field so that in pushes the vertical borders. Then do a carriage return and write something again.
You will get something like this:
https://i.imgur.com/jiQJ4Zq.png
The text is centered on the initial center, i.e. 50px, not the new center.

Comment: hmmm, does `text-align: center;` help?

Comment: No because it's already here. I gave the example of the editable paragraph but the solution might be something else.

Comment: I edited the answer added `min-width: 100px;` let me if that works for you.